# Can one do anything to make a cold take a milder course after noticing first symptoms?

Tags: prevention, common-cold, symptoms

Usually, a person will start feeling the symptoms of a cold a day or so after having been exposed to cold weather wearing improper clothing.

The question is this: what can I do to minimize the symptoms from that point on, or shorten the duration of the illness? Assume that it is indeed a common cold, not some other infection.

Comment: "I think it's a cold, maybe something else, doesn't affect the question" Actually, I think the question should be reworded to only refer to the common cold. Making it about every possible illness is insanely broad, so it is unanswerable in the current state and should be closed by the site's rules. Asking how to minimize the symptoms of a started cold, on the other hand, is a good question.

Comment: @rumtscho I'll edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Now that the question has been closed, I took the liberty of rewording it to the point where I think it can be opened again. I had two major problems with it before: First, it asked for "illness" in general, but as I said before, that's too broad to answer. Second, you were talking about "prevention" but clearly stated that you are asking about "after the symtpoms appear". At that point, you are already sick, and cannot prevent getting sick any more. I'm sorry I did such a major edit, but I think it was important in order to save the question. Voting for reopen.